# failed install npm && dev

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying `npm install && run dev` in laravel 8, but failed like this can you help me, please?

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/laravel-mix failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.24.35:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\NI\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-19T06_27_05_986Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and able to solve this by running following command:

```
npm config delete proxy
```